# How to check internet connection in unity without fps drop

Tags: unity-game-engine, websocket, connection, frame-rate

I'm working in Unity on a VR project. In this project we have websockets. For some internet issues we want to check if the websocket is still alive or on error and if this is the case we want to check the internet connection. if the internet is up again it needs to reconnect to the websocket or reinitialized it. We do it now in the update function with a timer that fires every second but every second there is a fps drop for checking the internet. Is there another way around this?

```
public float waitTime = 1f;
private float timer;

private void Update()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if (timer > waitTime)
    {
        //check if websocket is alive or that it must re initialized
        if (webSocket != null) //check if websocket was allready initialized 
        {
            if (isSocketError && Application.internetReachability != NetworkReachability.NotReachable) // check if an error was given by the websocket and ethernet is available again
            {
                CreateWebsocketSession(sessionId);
            }
            else if ((!webSocket.IsAlive || !webSocket.IsConnected) && Application.internetReachability != NetworkReachability.NotReachable) // check if websocket is alive and internet is available.
            {
                CreateWebsocketSession(sessionId);
            }
        }


        timer = 0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking it in the update function, is it not possible to check it at the start of whatever internet action you would like to execute?

Comment: You have to get this out of the update for sure. If you are using that connection you can check it in the code where you transferring the data.

Comment: The problem is that at a random point the data comes in. At the vr application it could random gets a message and we want to check the internet state of the websocket is alive and if it isn't that it must reconnect as fast as possible. Thats why it is in the update because the user has no interaction.

Comment: for the architecture we have a backend, a vr device and a frontend. where the backend is offcourse the socket server for both applications. and we want to send data from the front > backend > vr device. so there is no user input where we can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you call a function, it runs to completion before returning. This
>   effectively means that any action taking place in a function must
>   happen within a single frame update

I normaly check internet connection pinging Google (`Application.internetReachability` isn't a good way to determine the actual connectivity: [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-internetReachability.html))

```
IEnumerator checkInternetConnection(Action<bool> action){
     WWW www = new WWW("http://google.com");
     yield return www;//wait for execution of this row, executed at Time x
     if (www.error != null) {//executed at time x+y, where y is the execution time(i think where you have drops)
         action (false);
     } else {
         action (true);//got internet here
     }
 }
```

In your case, use a `Coroutine()` with yields instead of `Update()`